# Cannot install Docker container for SQL Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to install `SQL Server` on my `Docker` but I am not sure if I should create a Docker container first and then install `SQL Server` image e.g. `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server 2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04`. I have a `SQL Server` database container but I want to create a new container for this new database.

I tried to run this command via `cmd`, but it does not create a container (I am not sure if I should restart Docker to see the changes).

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04
```

There is a message: *"Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU4-ubuntu-18.04"*. I think it is due to that it already installed. But I am not sure how can I create a new container using this image (for SQL Server database).

Another issue as I have no experience with `Docker`, should I use `cmd`, `Windows Power Shell`, etc. for running `Docker` commands?

Comment: Does anybody else have not used SQL Server on a Docker container? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipically, there is a Docker image with SQL Server, and a container is ran based on this. So, if you perform a `docker run` (as in the instructions of the next link) you would be pulling the image from the [Docker Hub repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) - getting a copy of the image to your machine, if you still don't have one - and creating a running container based on the image.

Please look at [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-mssql-docker-container-800166ecca21) for a complete walkthrough on building an MSSQL Docker container.

To run two containers from the same image, use diferent names, ports and volumes - since it is a database - for each container, and that should do. Please, check this [example](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-multiple-containers-of-the-same-image-and-expose-different-ports.amp).

Regarding the consoles, you can use any of your choice. Using Windows, personally I prefer a "shell-like" console, like *Git Bash* or *WSL shell*. Docker is Linux, so for me it makes sense to use a "Linux-like" environment and commands. But you only have to install the *Docker Desktop*, then it is up to you. Aditionally, you can install the *Docker extension* for *Visual Studio Code* or any other manager, since it allows you to manage your containers, images, volumes, etc. very easily :)

Concerning the volumes strategy, that depends on what you want to do with the container. If you don't specify any volume, you will lose all the data, once you delete the container. If you use a named volume, you let Docker manage the location of the information, but it becomes attached to that name and you can see that in your volumes list; you'll lose the data only if you delete that specific volume. Whereas if you use a volume mounted to an external location, for example in your file system, you can specify that the data is stored in such location; only if you go to the location and delete the data, will the information be lost. So, it's up to your use case :)

Docker [documentation on volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) is quite good and you can read here the [differences between named and path based volumes](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-28-named-volumes-vs-path-based-volumes#:%7E:text=Path%20based%20volumes%20serve%20the,directory%20on%20the%20Docker%20host.)

Comment: Ok, voted up. No problem, you can accept the answer now and vote up later, if you wish :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about my last questions? >>>

Comment: Many thanks, voted up. I see that first I pull an image that I install and then create a container using this pulled image and necessary parameters. But I am wondering should I keep the SQL Server data files in the Docker container's default SQL installation directory or a dedicated volume of this container or local drive? Which one would you suggest and how can I perform it?

Comment: I was editing the post answer to include the volumes part, please check it out :)

Comment: Very useful explanations, voted up ;) But although I have a look at Volume sections, I could not understand properly. So, I just want to keep my SQL Server database related files to a volume and keep it after deleting the container. I am not sure which steps I should follow? Any specific point please?

Comment: Thanks :) Well, you can go through own MS documentation, they carefully explain it - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)